Combine 2 object values in array and update object
I have the following array:
const arr = [{name:"test",name2:"ing"},{name:"desc",name2:"ription"}]

I want to combine name and name2 in object and add new key in the same object
Expected Output:
const arr = [
    {
        name: "test",
        name2: "ing",
        fullname: "testing"
    },
    {
        name: "desc",
        name2: "ription",
        fullname: "description"
    },
];

This is what I have tried:
arr.forEach((ele,i)=> {
    Object.values(arr[i]).push(ele.name+''+ele.name2)
})


You almost have it.  Try this simple solution!


const arr = [{name:"test",name2:"ing"},{name:"desc",name2:"ription"}];
arr.forEach(ele => ele.fullname = ele.name + ele.name2);
console.log(arr);



